# torch.cuda.is_available() returns False on ssh server with NVIDIA GPU

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, gpu, conda

I am using my Institute GPU through ssh server (Pardon the terms, I am a newbie). I have been trying for so long but PyTorch does not have access to the CUDA devices.

Here is a list of the devices attached:

[image]

I have also run some commands: `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False`, while `torch.backend.cudnn.enabled` is `True`. I have tried with `cudatoolkit 10.2` and `cudatoolkit 11.1`, as well as `cudatoolkit 11.3` also and I am still not being able to make a conda environment.

Any help is appreciated. The results here are for `PyTorch 1.10.0` and `cudatoolkit 10.1.243`.

[image]

Here is conda list torch.
[image]

As mentioned by @Ravi Mashru, I created a new environment. Here is the result now.
[image]

Comment: Could you show `conda list torch`? Also, what do you mean by *I am still not being able to make a conda environment*?

Comment: @Ivan, thanks for replying. I have added the image for conda list torch. I misframe when I said, "I am still not being able to make a conda environment". I wanted to say that I am doing all these installations using conda. Pardon me, I am new to these technicalities.

Comment: How did you install PyTorch? Are you sure that you used the correct version corresponding to the Cuda version?

Comment: @Tom, I have installed it using the commands on the official PyTorch website. I researched and everything points to version mismatch, but I am not being able to correct it.

Comment: From the list it looks like you have the CPU build of PyTorch installed. Is it possible for you to create a new conda environment and try installing PyTorch there using the instructions on the official site?

Comment: @Ravi Mashru I have installed from the official site using this command (Changing only version). conda install pytorch==1.8.0 torchvision==0.9.0 torchaudio==0.8.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch. It is written this command is for GPU

Comment: From the screenshot I see that torch was installed from the pypi channel instead of the pytorch channel mentioned in the official docs. That's why I suggest creating a new conda environment and trying to install PyTorch there.

Comment: @Ravi Mashru, can you please link a the source so that I might not make the same mistake doing it again

Comment: I think you've got the command right. It's the same one you've posted above.

Comment: @Ravi Mashru Can you think of some other error that might be occurring then?

Comment: I don't think there would be an error. The fact that torch was installed from pypi makes me believe torch was already installed before in the base environment that is active. Otherwise, if torch was installed when you ran the command from the official site then the channel shown would be "pytorch". And maybe it is the CPU build that was installed beforehand which is why it isn't using the GPU. Again, this is just a guess. The only way to verify would be creating a fresh new conda environment and installing there.

Comment: I also see it like @RaviMashru

Comment: @RaviMashru, I created a new environment and have updated the question. It would be really helpful if you could look at the results.

Comment: From the `nvidia-smi` output I see you have CUDA 11.4 installed. Is there any particular reason why you've installed the cuda10.2 version of PyTorch?

Comment: @RaviMashru, I had also tried 11.1 but it didn't work either. There is no particular reason I tried 10.2 though.

Comment: Do you get the same error with CUDA 11 as well?

Comment: @RaviMashru yes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to help further. I would recommend asking in the PyTorch forums while you wait for an answer here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/

Comment: Ok thanks @RaviMashru

Comment: I am not sure because I never use conda, but do you also have to install the cuda toolkit in the conda environment? In this article someone explains it with TensorFlow: https://towardsdatascience.com/setting-up-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-and-anaconda-onwindows-2ee9c39b5c44

Comment: @Tom, I have done everything. Nothing worked. I'm still trying.